# Как установить определенное количество пробелов в sep

Tags: python

[image: Вот, на изображении вывод это как у меня получается. но я не понимаю как написать вторую линию, чтобы везде выходил нормальный прямоугольник.**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом]

вот сама задача:
Напиши программу, которая выводит прямоугольник. По периметру он должен состоять из введённых пользователем символов. Его ширина — настраиваемая, а высота равна трём символам. Знаю что можно просто понаставить прабелов, но когда значение ширины будет меняться, прямоугольник не получится

мой код:

```
simb = input()
num = int(input())
first_line = simb*num
print(first_line)
print(simb, simb, sep="")        вот тут в sep нужно что-то поставить чтоб расстояние менялось
second_line = simb*num
print(second_line)
```

Comment: `sep=" " * (num - 2)` — учитывая, что вы уже и так используете `*num`, могли бы и сами догадаться наверное...

Comment: зачем вам две разные переменые first_line и  second_line, если они абсолютно одинаковые?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = str(input())
y = int(input())
print(x * y)
print(x, x, sep=" " * (y - 2))
print(x * y)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]